# What is the difference between “ " quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what is difference between these two quotes in javascript “ " as

“ --> this gives an error

However,

" --> this does not

Comment: the " marks the beginning or an ending of a String. The “ gives an error because it's not known to the interpreter.

Comment: `"` is an (ascii) double quote, and has meaning to javascript - whatever the other one is, has no meaning to javascript

Comment: Okay.. So where does the difference lie? I mean how does the interpreter know these two are different. Are there ASCII value different or something of that sort?

Comment: @VarunGrover yes: one is an ASCII double quote, one is a Unicode smart quote. The spec allows one, the other came later.

Comment: This is the same as asking 'how does the interpreter know the difference between " and {', or any other arbitrary symbol. It knows because they're different characters.

Comment: Related: [Simple HTML page not loading Javascript Hello World](/q/22713330/4642212), and [JavaScript: a simple 'compare' function not working?](/q/16726570/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the specification, section 11.8.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-string-literals):

> A string literal is zero or more Unicode code points enclosed in single or double quotes...
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> StringLiteral ::
>     " DoubleStringCharactersopt "
>     ' SingleStringCharactersopt '
> ```

JS string literals may use single or double quotes, but not smart quotes. They are not recognized as delimiters for a string literal, hence your error:

```js
console.log("Look friends, “fake quotes”!");
```

With ES6+, [template literals were introduced (s11.8.6)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components), which use backticks (```) rather than quotes.

This is somewhat in contrast to JS' rules on variable names, which *may* use Unicode characters, although they are still not interchangeable.

Comment: @Kaii I'm not sure what that edits adds that the quote from the specification does not, so I've rolled it back. If you think they cover different things, please let me know.